# Como testar WebServices php em Android com biblioteca Retrofit

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo Android no Android Studio e estou usando a biblioteca retrofit para conectar com um servidor php. Quero saber como eu faço para testar esse app em um celular real com o servidor rodando no meu notebook. No caso, qual a estrutura que eu tenho que montar para realizar o teste?

Comment: Existem diversas formas de fazer isso e existem milhares de postagens/tutoriais na internet ensinando a fazer isso do zero. Para que sua pergunta seja respondida, você teria que ser mais objetivo em relação a algum problema que você teve ao tentar implementar algum exemplo de consumo de webservice.

Comment: @acklay eu estava pensando em conectar o celular e o notebook na minha rede wifi e colocar o ip do meu notebook no código do app que faz a chamada do Web Services. Isso daria certo?

Comment: Sim @MatheusEmanuel, daria certo pois é assim que eu faço na empresa que trabalho quando preciso testar meus serviços nos apps.